# Phaser js, щели между тайлами

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tilemap

Проблема в том, что создаю карту с помощью Tiled и загружаю в фейзере ее вместе с ассетами.

```
this.load.image("tiles", "/assets/map/dungeon.png");
this.load.tilemapTiledJSON("map", "/assets/map/dungeon2.json");
...
map = this.make.tilemap({key:'map',width: 32, height: 32});
tileset = map.addTilesetImage("dungeon","tiles");
Background = map.createStaticLayer('Background',tileset,0,0);
Floor = map.createStaticLayer('Floor',tileset,0,0);
DecoFloor = map.createStaticLayer('FloorDeco',tileset,0,0);
Wall = map.createStaticLayer('Wall',tileset,0,0);
Deco = map.createStaticLayer('Deco',tileset,0,0);
```

В результате карта сторится и даже работают колайдеры размеченные в Tiled, но между тайлами появляются такие зазоры.
[image: Скрин пробелемы]

Уже пробовал рисовать различные карты, ассеты и даже нарисовать свой пак ассетов, проблема вылазит везде 
(Использую phaser3)

Comment: это находили? https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/3352

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да, если вообще камеру отключить, то проблема решается, но   this.cameras.main.roundPixels = true;
у меня выставлен, результат на скрине

Answer (score 0):

Из-за кривости фейзера может помочь только экструзия тайлов.
Вот ссылка на пакет вместе с туториалом, надеюсь кому-то поможет.

https://github.com/sporadic-labs/tile-extruder

Устанавливаем через **NPM** и вызываем

```
tile-extruder --tileWidth ШиринаТайла --tileHeight ВысотаТайла --margin 0 --spacing 0 --input ПутьКТайлам --output ПутьНавыход
```

Создасться новый тайлсет расширенный утилитой и потом меняем путь на него в Tiled и подменям отступ на 1 и пропуск на 2